# Array.map returns cannot read property map of null

Tags: javascript

I want to display a list of elements I have in Json.

json is for example:

> [{"res": "1030-1130"},{"res":
>   "1200-1400"},{"res": "1800-1930"}]

my code is :

```
render () {
    const items = this.state.JsonList.map(item => <li>{item.res}</li> );
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items}
        </ul>
      </div>
```

But I have the error
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null**

But if I make a console.log of this.state.JsonList it is not empty and returns:

> 0: {res: "1030-1130"} 1: {res: "1200-1400"} 2: {res: "1800-1930"}

Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: Is that JsonList an Array? Could you please paste the console.log result? Thanks

Comment: @tarabor : yes it is an array. I edited the answer to complete

Comment: `this.state.JsonList` is `null`, isn't that obvious?

Comment: try `const items = JSON.parse(this.state.JsonList).map(item => <li>{item.res}</li> );`

Comment: can you please share the whole component code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your example:

```
render () {
  // never use upper case to store an array, try to change that as earliest as possible
  const { JsonList: jsonList } = this.state; 
  const items = jsonList.map((item) => <li key={item.res}>{item.res}</li> );
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`map` is a method of `array`, if you doubt that your value is an array, you can do as follow:

```
  const items = [...jsonList].map(item => <li key={item.res}>{item.res}</li>);
```

The `console.log` seems to show that it is not an array, try also to log it's type

```
 console.log(jsonList instanceof Array); // should return true
 console.log(typeof jsonList); // should be array not a string
```

If it's a string, don't forget to `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse(jsonList).map((item) => <li key={item.res}>{item.res}</li>);
```

In the end, if your value is `null` during initialization of your component, you can do:

```
  const { JsonList: jsonList = [] } = this.state; 
  // or instead doing this in render, do it during state initialization
```

Note that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null` is an explicit error when we try to access `.map` on `null`.

Answer (score 1):

you are facing this issue because this.state.JsonList is null during the render method call, to solve this

```
render() {
 const { JsonList: jsonList = [] } = this.state; // if the jsonList is empty it will have default empty array value, hence null value error will not occur
 const items = jsonList.map(item => <li>{item.res}</li> );
 return (
   <div>
      <ul>
        {items}
      </ul>
    </div>
 );  
}
```

hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a reduce function as well instead of map

```
'var jsonlist= [{"res": "1030-1130"},{"res": "1200-1400"},{"res": "1800-1930"}];

function appendlist(total, num) {
  return total + '<li>' + num.res + '</li><br>';
}

function render(item) {
   return jsonlist.reduce(appendlist);
}'
```